# Instagram Embedding No Longer Works When Not Logged In

Tags: instagram, embed

If you are not logged into Instagram on a certain browser, any page that has Instagram embedded will not render properly.

I believe Instagram may have just changed this, or perhaps I just noticed it? But, is there any way to have Instagram embed properly without a user being logged in on a browser?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was that I think Instagram had a bug in their script and then they fixed it because I changed nothing and it started working again. Yay!